# Standard lib path of g++. And how to add new ones

Tags: gcc, debian, googletest

I want to use gtest but execution tells me

```
./netTest: error while loading shared libraries: libgtest.so.0:
  cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

1. What are standard paths in that gcc linker looks for libs
2. What is standard path of Debian to store libs
3. How do I add libpaths to g++ (-L flag correct?)

Note on 2: I ask because the libs of gtest are in `/usr/local/libs/` but in there is just python and gtest. All other libs are in `/usr/lib/`. Hence i guess the gtest installer made something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PS. Perhaps you could just instal the Debian `libgtest-dev` package (if there's one).

> 1. What are standard paths in that gcc linker looks for libs

You can see it with `gcc -v -x c /dev/null -o /dev/null 2>&1 | grep LIBRARY_PATH`

> 1. What is standard path of Debian to store libs

Perhaps you meant where the dynamic loader will look for shared libraries.
Check `/etc/ld.so.conf` and/or files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.

> 1. How do I add libpaths to g++ (-L flag correct?)

You can use the `--rpath` option to `ld`. However, I would suggest using it only during development and not in deployment.

You can also set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the location of your `libgtest.so.0`.

Comment: libgtest-dev are just header of v1.5. libgtest0, the shared library, is not available on debian wheezy. ls.so.conf content:`include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`. /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf content: `/usr/local/lib`. Thats exactly where libgtest.so.0 lies. Why do I get this erro mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the preceeding problem. gTest does not use precompiled libs anymore.

> ```
>   Use of precompiled libgtest Not Recommended
>   -------------------------------------------
>
> The Google C++ Testing Framework uses conditional compilation for some
> things.  Because of the C++ "One Definition Rule", gtest must be
> compiled with exactly the same flags as your C++ code under test.
> Because this is hard to manage, upstream no longer recommends using
> precompiled libraries [1].
> ```
>
> -- Steve M. Robbins , Sat, 21 Apr 2012 17:00:56 -0500

Well doesnt surprise me anymore why I did not find the library in Wheezy :)